# Best practice to grant only necessary permissions to Kubernetes cluster user and pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Even though new to kubernetes clusters, I am assigned to deploy and administrate one for my lab. For now, pods with pytorch containers using gpus (those will be the most typical kind of pods to be deployed in my settings) are running peachy on the cluster, in spite of some permission issues:

1. One user, `tom` for example, can delete pods deployed by another user, `jerry` for example.
2. Containers are running as `root`. Again, let's take `jerry` for example. Suppose that `jerry` deploys a pod manifested with containers that mount a directory with files owned by various other users. Running as `root` means `jerry` can not only modify their own files, but also files owned by `tom`, even by `spike` and `tyke`. Such a manifest would probably look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gpu-pod
  namespace: default # this field should be properly configured
  # if I want to restrict user access to certain resources,
  # usually pods.
spec:
  runtimeClassName: nvidia
  nodeSelector:
    nvidia.com/gpu: 'true'
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: cuda-container
      image: mylab.registry:5000/espnet/espnet:gpu-latest
      command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo "running following scripts"
        ls /data
        ls /exp
        nvidia-smi
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 4
      volumeMounts:
      - name: data-volume
        mountPath: /data
      - name: exp-volume
        mountPath: /exp
  volumes:
  - name: data-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /data
  - name: exp-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /exp # where directories owned by tom, jerry,
      # spike and tyke are located.
      # on the host machine, this directory is actually
      # a mounted nfs path served by other machine.
```

Actually, Kubernetes does provide me with weapons to tackle these problems, to be precise, [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and [Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/). It seems that the 1st issue can be addressed by creating multiple namespaces or hierarchical ones and configuring correct permissions to namespaces for different roles, but I am not yet sure that will work.

However, as for the 2nd issue, a security context allows containers to run in a non-root mode with access only to certain files, despite that some (in fact, far too many pulled from Internet) images must run rootfully thus need a rebuild. However, it seems that I have to ultimately count on a user's good conduct to only deploy pods with correct `securityContext` field in manifest.

As a cluster admin, what can I do to avoid the aforementioned 2 permission issues? Are there any kubernetes plugins right there for me to process permissions automatically? Or when every option is exhausted, should I deploy a system-wide program that intercepts every `kubectl apply` command, overwrites the manifest, and applies the modified version instead?

Comment: You should generally put users in different namespaces if you do not want them to have access to the same resources. A container that runs as `root` is not able to mount filesystems (without explicitly granting additional privileges).

Comment: @larsks Thank you for your rapid and concise advice. I'm glad you have confirmed that namespace is the essential solution, dissolving my doubts. But I cannot fully grasp it that "A container that runs as root is not able to mount filesystems". Would you mind elaborating a bit further on this? I've attached a running example (a manifest) during my last edit. After such a pod is created, I've tested by attaching shell to the container to find that the running user is root and has permission to every subdirectory in the mounted filesystem.

Comment: I mean the fact that the container is running as the `root` user has no impact over what filesystems it can mount -- that is controlled by the manifest; you cannot run the `mount` command inside the container. You should generally not be using `hostPath` style mounts for exactly the reasons you mention in your previous comment; consider another solution (NFS, Ceph, [etc](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html)).

Comment: @larsks Thanks for your clear additional explanation. In fact, after reading your last comment, it strikes me that I had come across the advice against using `hostPath` before, but I hadn't paid much attention at the time. Now, with your repeated advice, I realize the importance of choosing proper mounting styles. I would gladly use direct nfs in this case. Thank you again for your brief but informative advice.